# How can I calculate in R a region (country) average for satellite data?

Tags: r, border, pixel

I have a matrix (latitude and longitude) of satellite data and I want to calculate the average value for different countries. I can plot the data with the raster library and add the country borders reading from a rds countour, but how can I extract only the pixels that are inside the border?
Thanks

Edit:
It's a 720 x 360 matrix filled with NO2 concentration values (0.5º x 0.5º), grabbed from satellite data and I want to calculate the average value four each country in South America.
I downloaded the countries contours from [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raster::extract` for this

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed this function